# MobGUI: set button touched state

Tags: user-interface, button, mobile, livecode

On LiveCode I can set the button's touched (hilited) state by the following script:

```
 set the hilited of button "Button1" to true
```

Is there a way where I can control/set the touched state of a button created using MobGUI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an in-built hilite property for mobGui buttons but something like the following should do it-

```
set the foreColor of fld "mgcLabel" of group "button name here " to gray
```